# Read Databricks dbfs file (.tpe) without using dbutils

Tags: python, azure, databricks

I have a file with '.tpe' format in my Gen 2 storage account, but I am not able to read it in databricks and get this error

**FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:**

```
gen2_path =f'/mnt/{CONTAINER}@{STORAGE_ACCOUNT}/test/input/example.tpe'

dbfs_path = /dbfs/FileStore/test/input/example.tpe'

with open(gen2_path , "rb") as f:
   byte = f.read(1)
```

but the same file I am able to read it from the dbfs in databricks. Can someone help how I can read this in databricks from storage account?

`dbutils.fs.ls(gen2_path)`

Output:

```
[FileInfo(path='dbfs:/mnt/cur-cdms@[REDACTED]/test/input/example.tpe', name='example.tpe', size=1594794)]
```

Comment: What's `CONTAINER` and what's `STORAGE_ACCOUNT`? The error message is clear and it has nothing to do with the file format. Try printing `path` before you open it (That should go after `No such file or directory:` but you didn't cut it off)

Comment: I just noticed, `path` is not defined unless that's not the full code, change that for `gen2_path`

Comment: You can't read it because it doesn't exist at the path you've given. That's what FileNotFoundError means

Comment: @Daviid storage account and container are placeholders for the names of my container and storage account. and its gen2_path(it was a type earlier)

Comment: @DarkKnight also modified the code in the question, was just a typo

Comment: @Daviid there's nothing wrong in the path, it just prints whatevr's there,
it works when i am listing using dbutils, so the path isn't any issue, the issue is its a unique format and there must be a way to read that

Comment: @userrrr The exception has nothing to do with the file's contents. *open()* simply cannot find the file

Comment: @Daviid found the solution
i just had to add /dbfs at the front of the gen2_path 
modified it like this and it works 
gen2_path =f'/dbfs/mnt/{CONTAINER}@{STORAGE_ACCOUNT}/test/input/example.tpe'

Comment: @DarkKnight found the solution
i just had to add /dbfs at the front of the gen2_path 
modified it like this and it works 
gen2_path =f'/dbfs/mnt/{CONTAINER}@{STORAGE_ACCOUNT}/test/input/example.tpe'

Comment: kindly remove the negative review

Answer (score 0):

You have a file at `dbfs:/mnt/.../example.tpe`, while trying to open file `/mnt/.../example.tpe` - that a difference - first path refers to DBFS filesystem, the second is a local directory.

The reason why `dbutils.fs.ls(gen2_path)` works is that it assumes to receive path relative to DBFS root as a parameter. It means it actually reads file from `f'dbfs:/{gen2_path}'`.

DBFS itself is mounted on drivers and executors at '/dbfs', therefore the local path you need to use is `/dbfs/mnt/.../example.tpe`:

```
with open(f"/dbfs/{gen2_path}" , "rb") as f:
   byte = f.read(1)
```